# Looping through all main() arguments

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, arguments, program-entry-point

- The application will request a series of input words/string using the
  main arguments.
- It will determine if per input string entered
  ends in a consonant, a vowel, an odd number, an even number, or a
  special symbol.
- It should also be able to count the number of
  characters per word input.

So far, this is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length > 0) {
        String regExVowels = ".*[AEIOUaeiou]$";
        // regEx Strings

        char[] caMainArg = null;
        String strMainArg = null;

        for(String arg: args) {
            // Convert each String arg to char array
            caMainArg = arg.toCharArray();

            // Convert each char array to String
            strMainArg = new String(caMainArg);
        }

        System.out.print(strMainArg + " - " + strMainArg.length());

        // if-else conditions

    } else {
        System.out.println("No arguments passed!");
    }
}
```

It works, but it only takes the last argument. For example:

***Eclipse > Run Configurations... > Arguments***

```
kate middleton sep30 jan25 `
```

It will only output:

```
` - 1 - special character
```

My desired output is:

```
kate - 4 - vowel
middleton - 9 - consonant
sep30 - even number
jan25 - odd number
` - 1 - special character
```

I am unsure as to how to loop through the arguments and print the appropriate results.

Comment: Is this homework?  If it is please tag it as such.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW [`homework` tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @Pshemo thanks, I wasn't aware of the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You close your `for` loop too early.

You do:

```
   for(String arg: args) {
        // Convert each String arg to char array
        caMainArg = arg.toCharArray();

        // Convert each char array to String
        strMainArg = new String(caMainArg);
    }
    System.out.print(strMainArg + " - " + strMainArg.length());

    if(regExVowels.matches(strMainArg)) {
        System.out.print(" - vowel");

    } else if(regExUpperConsonants.matches(strMainArg) ||

    .....
```

You need to do :

```
   for(String arg: args) {
        // Convert each String arg to char array
        caMainArg = arg.toCharArray();

        // Convert each char array to String
        strMainArg = new String(caMainArg);
        System.out.print(strMainArg + " - " + strMainArg.length());

        if(regExVowels.matches(strMainArg)) {
            System.out.print(" - vowel");

        } else if(regExUpperConsonants.matches(strMainArg) ||

        ....

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind assistance. Marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put,

```
    System.out.print(strMainArg + " - " + strMainArg.length());

    if(regExVowels.matches(strMainArg)) {
        System.out.print(" - vowel");

    } else if(regExUpperConsonants.matches(strMainArg) ||
            regExLowerConsonants.matches(strMainArg)) {
        System.out.print(" - consonant");

    } else if(regExEven.matches(strMainArg))    {
        System.out.print(" - even number");

    } else if(regExOdd.matches(strMainArg)) {
        System.out.print(" - odd number");

    } else {
        System.out.print(" - special character");
    }
```

Inside your loop towards the bottom that you already have that does loop through the arguments, your "for(String arg: args) {" line about 10 lines down.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, because you should move this:

```
System.out.print(strMainArg + " - " + strMainArg.length());

if(regExVowels.matches(strMainArg)) {
    System.out.print(" - vowel");

} else if(regExUpperConsonants.matches(strMainArg) ||
    regExLowerConsonants.matches(strMainArg)) {
    System.out.print(" - consonant");

} else if(regExEven.matches(strMainArg))    {
    System.out.print(" - even number");

} else if(regExOdd.matches(strMainArg)) {
    System.out.print(" - odd number");

} else {
    System.out.print(" - special character");
}
```

inside you loop, because want to check all your arguments, not only the last one.

Comment: Thank you, I believe the last }else{ must not be included.